# R - Add text & sentence ID column from row contents

Tags: r

I hope it's not a stupid question. I have data in this format

```
# id 001
# This is a sentence.
# text_sentence 001_01
1   This
2   is
3   a
4   sentence
# id 002
# This is also a sentence.
# text_sentence 001_02
1   This
2   is
3   also
4   a
5   sentence
# id 003
# This too is a sentence.
# text_sentence 002_01
1   This
2   too
3   is
4   a
5   sentence
```

Each numbered row has 8 columns. Rows starting with # are just one column. I need to transform the data so that each text and sentence number constitute a new column. I would also delete the rows beginning with # (I suppose that's easy enough with filter()), but I cannot figure out how to target the numbers in the third 'comment' rows so the data is looking like this:

```
001   01   1   This
001   01   2   is
001   01   3   a
001   01   4   sentence
001   02   1   This
001   02   2   is
001   02   3   also
001   02   4   a
001   02   5   sentence
002   01   1   This
002   01   2   too    
002   01   3   is
002   01   4   a    
002   01   5   sentence
```

I have some 50 texts like this ready for analysis, each with hundreds or thousands of rows, so it's not something to do by hand. I'm relatively new to this type of data analysis, but nothing I've read describes a transformation like this. It's probably super easy, but if someone has an idea, I'd be much obliged.

Comment: What have you tried? Responses are using more forthcoming when the OP has a go themselves and specifies where they are having a problem. Read about providing a [mcve]

Comment: Well, creating a new column is no problem, and I've used mutate to create new columns with data from operations using values from other cells in the same row. But the thing I cannot figure out (or even figure out how to search for) is how to zero in on that value at the end of each third 'comment' line and use it in multiple different rows where each sentence has a different number of words. It's hard to provide a minimal/complete/verifiable example when your question is about where to even start. Not asking for ready code, but a keyword or two to go on would be a big help.

Comment: I am having a hard time to imagine your data. If each sentence is a column, id001 has seven rows. id002 and 003 have eight rows. If you have all of them tofether in long format, there is no problem. But if each sentence stays in a column, I think you cannot produce a data frame since id001 has seven rows. Would you be able to provide a minimal sample data? Type `dput(yourobjectname)` in your R Console. Then, you will see a chunk of text. That is your data and you want to copy and paste it in your question.

Answer (score 1):

This uses a single regular expression function, `grepl`, and the `strsplit` function to extract the relevant values. It's a bit rough and ready; for example, it assumes the files have no missing header lines. It's enough to give you one idea of how to handle something like this. I've done this as if you'd write it out to a file, but it could just as easily be put into a data frame.

```
# your sample was saved in a file
# read the entire file into a vector
d <- readLines('test.txt')
# start with line 1
countLines <- 1
while (countLines <= length(d)) {
    # skip down to the third header line
    countLines <- countLines + 2
    # process it
    currLine <- d[countLines]
    # split on spaces then on underscore to extract
    # the i.d. and the sentence number
    idset <- strsplit(strsplit(currLine, ' ')[[1]][3], '_')
    countLines <- countLines + 1
    # write out the words until the next header line
    # that is, a line without a digit in the first column
    while(grepl('^\\d',d[countLines])) {
        print(sprintf('%s   %s   %s', idset[[1]][1], idset[[1]][2], d[countLines]))
        countLines <- countLines + 1
    }
}
```

The `strsplit` function returns a list consisting of 1 item—a vector of characters. `idset[[1]]` is the sole list element; `idset[[1]][1]` is the first item in the character vector. So a line like `# text_sentence 002_01` will be split into three chunks then the third chunk into two chunks.

The pattern sought by the `grepl` function is a digit (`\\d`) which is the first character in the line (`^`).

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

Code:

```
# data is stored in data.frame df

# Find lines with id
idLine <- grep("^# id ", df$V1)
# [1]  1  8 16
# Iterate over all id's
result <- lapply(seq_along(idLine), function(i) {
    # Extract line in which id was found
    x <- idLine[i]
    # Extract ID from id line
    ID1 <- sub(".* ", "", df$V1[x])
    # Extract second ID from id line + 2
    ID2 <- sub(".*_", "", df$V1[x + 2])
    # Extract text between current and following id
    sentence <- df[(x + 3):(ifelse(i != length(idLine), idLine[i + 1] - 1, nrow(df))), ]
    data.frame(ID1, ID2, 
               num = as.numeric(sub(" .*", "" ,sentence)), 
               text = sub(".* ", "" ,sentence))
})
do.call(rbind, result)
```

Result:

```
# ID1 ID2 num     text
# 001  01   1     This
# 001  01   2       is
# 001  01   3        a
# 001  01   4 sentence
# 002  02   1     This
# 002  02   2       is
# 002  02   3     also
# 002  02   4        a
# 002  02   5 sentence
# 003  01   1     This
# 003  01   2      too
# 003  01   3       is
# 003  01   4        a
# 003  01   5 sentence
```

Data (`df`):

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c("# id 001", "# This is a sentence.", "# text_sentence 001_01", 
"1   This", "2   is", "3   a", "4   sentence", "# id 002", "# This is also a sentence.", 
"# text_sentence 001_02", "1   This", "2   is", "3   also", "4   a", 
"5   sentence", "# id 003", "# This too is a sentence.", "# text_sentence 002_01", 
"1   This", "2   too", "3   is", "4   a", "5   sentence")), .Names = "V1", row.names = c(NA, 
-23L), class = "data.frame")
```

You can read in your data using `readLines(file.txt)` or `data.table::fread("file.txt", sep = "\n")`